# C# - Add to a static dictionary values locally

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I got this code

```
static Dictionary<string, XElement> DName = new Dictionary<string, string> { };
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     DName.Add("RO","FL");
    }
static void anotherMethod(){
Console.WriteLine(DName["RO"]);
//not working, while in Main works.
}
```

So how to access it from the other method?

Comment: Where is the other method located, i mean in what class?

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException was unhandled
  Message=The given key was not present in the dictionary.` the error, @TimSchmelter in the class Program, both of methods

Comment: Are you sure that `anotherMethod()` is called *after* you do the `Add`?

Comment: explain clearly what you want to do?

Comment: where you are callind the anothermethod?

Comment: Lol @TimothyGroote i'm so stupid, thanks for your fast reply :)

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;) but read what dasblinkenlight said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary `DName` is shared among all static and non-static methods of the class. The presence or absence of keys in that dictionary depends only on the timing of their insertion: if the call

```
DName.Add("RO","FL");
```

is made before the call of `anotherMethod()`, then `DName["RO"]` should see the value; if the call of `Add` is made after, or the key is deleted before the call of `anotherMethod()`, then lookup of the `"RO"` is going to fail.

Note that passing data through a static member variable is a very fragile approach. It is much better to pass parameters explicitly - it gives you a lot more control over what to pass:

```
static void AnotherMethod(IDictionary<string,string>){
    Console.WriteLine(dName["RO"]);
}
```